# Cannot get "npm install @feathers/cli -g" to work in the command line

Tags: npm, command-line, installation, feathersjs

I get this error message when I try installing feathers from npm

npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!

Help!!

Comment: It's just a warning, not an error. What is the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: I cannot get the feathersjs/cli to install. I want a feathers app and I cannot "feathers generate" without the package installed. It does not appear in the package.json file either

Comment: I just tried `npm install -g @feathersjs/cli` and while it did show me the warning, I'm able to run the `feathers generate app` command after npm finished. I'm on Windows. Which OS are you on? And what do you get when you run the generate command?

Comment: Also, it will not appear in package.json unless you include `--save` in the npm install command. So that's expected

Comment: I get "feathers: command not found" I am also on a windows

Comment: Can you paste the complete output of npm install? From the point of entering the command till it exits. I'm guessing maybe there's another error printed in the log. Possibly related to permissions.

Comment: I can second that I am experiencing the same issue, Win 10 Pro, node v8.10.0, npm v5.6.0, running `npm install -g @feathersjs/cli` from cmd with admin privileges. Same warnings. Terminal output from `feathers --version` is `'feathers' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Do I need to manually add it to path or something?

Comment: Interesting. For me it added a .cmd executable to the npm folder inside  %APPDATA%. And this directory is on PATH. But I did not add it to PATH. Check if you have the cmd file inside your `%APPDATA%\npm` folder, and if yes, try adding it to PATH manually.

Comment: Thanks @Vasan that seems to have been the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Vasan pointed out in the comments, running

`npm install -g @feathersjs/cli`

from the command prompt on Windows installs a file `feathers.cmd` in the folder:

`%APPDATA%\npm`

If this folder is *not* on your PATH, then feathers will not be recognised as an executable - it appears that the global install doesn't add it to the path automatically.

Editing system environment variables to add this folder to your path should make the feathers cli tools available.

Note that after altering your path you may need to restart your terminal for the updated path to be available.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, if you have an earlier version installed, uninstall the **old feathers-cli** using:

```
npm uninstall feathers-cli -g
```

Then install @feathersjs/cli and upgrade a project by the following commands:

```
npm install @feathersjs/cli -g
cd path/to/project
feathers upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the installation issue. But got an error: `404 Not Found: babel-messages@^6.23.0`. I've solved it when run `npm install @feathersjs/cli -g` through the **windows terminal** (cmd). Before that I was running it on **bash**.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also occurs when installation is ran using Admin credential(Windows 10), reinstall without elevated cmd/powershell credential also solved the problem.